# Add Custom Taxonomies to Custom post types automatically

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am building a website using Wordpress and Thesis theme where I would be using custom post type say 'Movie'. I also have an API which given the title of the movie Gives the list  of Genres it belongs to. I have "genres' Custom taxonomy already created.
I would like to know if there is any filter/action as 'Category_save_pre' where I can hook my API to assign the Genre automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try save_post - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post